# MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY

Tags: sql, laravel, mariadb

I build my project based on Laravel 9 and try to get count data by date group. I write using `DB::raw` to get sql query like this:

```
                $rawActive = "
                SELECT
                    SBC.SITE,
                    OPR.OPERATOR,
                    COUNT(*) TMO_COUNT,
                    DATE_FORMAT( TMO.TMO_DATE, '%m%Y' ) BULANTAHUN 
                FROM
                    TOP_TMO TMO
                    INNER JOIN SUBSCRIBER SBC ON TMO.SUBSCRIBER_ID = SBC.ID
                    INNER JOIN OPERATOR OPR ON SBC.SITE_ID = OPR.ID 
                WHERE
                    SBC.SITE_ID = ".$siteId." 
                GROUP BY
                    DATE_FORMAT(
                    TMO.TMO_DATE,
                    '%m%Y')
                ";
            
                $queryAct = DB::select(DB::raw($rawActive));
```

the `siteId` is from form request.

I search for some solutions include edit `'strict' => false,` in `database.php` , but still not find any solution.

I try to `return $rawActive`, and this is the result.

```
SELECT
SBC.SITE,
OPR.OPERATOR,
COUNT(*) TMO_COUNT,
DATE_FORMAT( TMO.TMO_DATE, '%m%Y' ) BULANTAHUN
FROM
TOP_TMO TMO
INNER JOIN SUBSCRIBER SBC ON TMO.SUBSCRIBER_ID = SBC.ID
INNER JOIN OPERATOR OPR ON SBC.SITE_ID = OPR.ID
WHERE
SBC.SITE_ID = 134
GROUP BY
DATE_FORMAT(
TMO.TMO_DATE,
'%m%Y')
```

As you can see, the `siteId` are seen well.

I also try this query on mysql, it's work fine.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please, `dd($siteId)` and show the results

Comment: there is no problem with that, the results are in accordance with the request I entered.

```$siteId = $request->site_id;``` . I enter 123 and it return 123

Comment: Your SQL syntax is OK. I even checked it in a SQL validator. I see no reason of this happening with the information you provided. And what has `'strict' => false` to do with your syntax error?

Comment: Provide **the value** of `$rawActive` which results in error, not the code which creates this value.

Comment: @ac.0101010111 I looked for solution and found that option, but it didnt work. Its still have same error

Comment: @Akina what do you mean? sorry i dont get it

Comment: @HafidMaulana `sticky` option has nothing to do your current setup unless you are using database cluster with nodes (master & slaves).

Comment: From the error it seems clear $siteId is not set or has an unexpected value at the time when you are setting $rawActive.  Don't just say that's not the problem - show us the value  of $rawActive

Comment: Also a good idea to always include the exact complete error message in your questions

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust `config\database.php` as below:

```
'mysql' => [
    ...
    ....
    'strict' => true,
    'modes' => [
        //'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY', // Disable this to allow grouping by one column
        'STRICT_TRANS_TABLES',
        'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE',
        'NO_ZERO_DATE',
        'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO',
        'NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER',
        'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'
    ],
]
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but it doesnt work. It still got same error

Comment: what is your MarriaDB version?

Comment: 10.4.21-MariaDB-1:10.4.21+maria~focal-log

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. You can enclose $siteId with single quote.  '123' will work same like 123 and it will helps breaking query when there is no value assigned in $siteId. Instead try to use parameterized query that will prevent this issue and also is recommended solution for securing raw query.

```
$rawActive = "
                SELECT
                    SBC.SITE,
                    OPR.OPERATOR,
                    COUNT(*) TMO_COUNT,
                    DATE_FORMAT( TMO.TMO_DATE, '%m%Y' ) BULANTAHUN 
                FROM
                    TOP_TMO TMO
                    INNER JOIN SUBSCRIBER SBC ON TMO.SUBSCRIBER_ID = SBC.ID
                    INNER JOIN OPERATOR OPR ON SBC.SITE_ID = OPR.ID 
                WHERE
                    SBC.SITE_ID = '".$siteId."' 
                GROUP BY
                    DATE_FORMAT(
                    TMO.TMO_DATE,
                    '%m%Y')
                ";
            
                $queryAct = DB::select(DB::raw($rawActive));
```